# Sending VM commands from a Jenkins pipeline

Tags: azure, powershell, jenkins, window, azure-cli

I'm building a Jenkins pipeline that should allow me to send remote commands to a Windows Machine.

For example, I want to move a file from one place to another. My pipeline code looks like this:

```
az vm run-command invoke  --command-id RunPowerShellScript --name VM_name -g test_g --scripts " Copy-Item  -Path C:\BuildFiles\File.xml  -Destination C:\Program Files (x86)\File\File Path\File version\"
```

From PowerShell, it works fine. But when I'm trying to run it from Jenkins as a bat script(I'm running Jenkins on windows) and adding the syntax `bat''` or `bat""` will give me syntax errors or invalidate my scripts.

Any way that I can make the script work?

Comment: please see my updated code response.  If my answer works I will edit your post to remove the trailing single quote

Comment: Hi vlad, please follow up and let me know if the solution provided works

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

You should not be using the `bat` function but rather the `powershell` function.  Your code should look like the following.

## Code

```
powershell label: '', script: '''
      az vm run-command invoke  
          --command-id RunPowerShellScript 
          --name VM_name 
          -g test_g 
          --scripts " 
               Copy-Item  
                  -Path C:\\BuildFiles\\File.xml  
                  -Destination C:\\Program Files (x86)\\File\\File Path\\File version\\"
    '''
```

Comment: Powershell is returning: "The string is missing the terminator: '."

Comment: code has been updated.  There was an extra single quote in the first example.  I modified it to use multiline command now

Comment: I have tried the code above, I'm getting `Missing expression after unary operator '--'.` after each parameter. I have tried to remove each extra space but it's the same. 
If I remove the multiple commands the script saved on the VM looks like this `Copy-Item  -Path C:\BuildFiles\File.xml  -Destination C:\Program Files (x86)\File\File Path\File version\" ` and in  Jenkins, I get "The string is missing the terminator: '." error